svndumpfilter is not completely filtering out specific directories
We need to shrink one of our svn repositories by removing a sub tree.
Running
svnrdump dump ... > repo.dump
svndumpfilter exclude trunk/tools < repo.dump > repo.dump.filtered
svnadmin load ... < repo.dump.filtered

seems to work, until the import process reaches a particular revision.
------- Committed revision 12122 >>>

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 12123
     * editing path : [PATH GOES HERE] ...COPIED... done.
     * editing path : [PATH GOES HERE] ... done.
     * editing path : [PATH GOES HERE]/tools/[PATH GOES HERE] ...


Further research shows that in revision 12123 in the original repository the trunk was branched and that there was a property change to a sub directory of the (now filtered out) 'tools' folder copied from 'trunk'.

To me it looks like svndumpfilter is 'forgetting' that the path ('trunk/tools') has been removed and so it keeps changes in later revisions that operate on non existing path repository elements.
Is there a way to force dumpfilter either to skip those operations, or create the path elements and leave only out the path contents, so the later operations (change properties on folders, ...) will still work.
